# Cross domain OData request using jQuery ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax, cross-domain, jsonp, odata

I am trying to make a cross domain OData request using jQuery ajax as follows.

Jquery

```
$(function () {
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:62526/OdataServer/Odata.svc/vw_listing&$format=json&$callback=?',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback: "addData"
 });
});

function addData(jsonString) {
for (var i = 0; jsonString.d[i] != null; i++) {
    $("#itemParent").append("<li>" + jsonString.d[i].Address + "</li>");
 }
}
```

Data Service

```
public class Odata : DataService< testEntities >
{

 public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
 {
    config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
    config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
 }
}
```

When I tried to call the dataservice using AJAX, I am getting a 400 error.

```
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
 http://localhost:56403/OdataServer/Odata.svc/vw_listing&$format=json&$callback=addData?_=1371713035531
```

Comment: Welcome to S.O. Could you add some details? What is the problem? What do you mean when you say "is not working"?

Comment: @DanieleArmanasco Thanks for your quick response. Updated the question. Added the error details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Solved my problem

```
$(function () {
$.getJSON('url?' +'$format=json&$callback=?',
    function (response) {
        $.each(response.d, function (index, value) {
          ............................

        })
    });
});
```

Shanz

Answer (score 0):

The parameter query string of your url needs to begin with a ?

```
'http://localhost:62526/OdataServer/Odata.svc/vw_listing?$format=json&$callback=?'
```